# Flutter Stateful Widget Passing Null

Tags: flutter, dart, stateful

Below are 1 stateless widget for the page, 1 stateful widget for repetitive purposes.
i realized i try to pass down the data from last page to be used here, and return initial value = null error.

actually this is the third place i did the modal route

[Picture: 2nd page code, fetch data from first page, and modal to third](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYftB.png)

as the picture, the _passData is from last page, and going to pass to next page as an object, am i doing right?

error occured
[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBHcZ.png)

errors shows that the data i passed is null. but when i test the passed data in stateless in 3rd page, not stateful in 3rd page (ie not calling stateful widget to passdata down), sometime it works some times it doesnt

Below are code for 3rd page whre

```
class EditDashboardCardDetailsScreen extends StatelessWidget {

  static const routeName = '/EditDashboardDetail';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _deedID =
        ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments as String; // is the id!
    final _loadedDeed = Provider.of<DeedsData>(context).findByKey(_deedID);
    String _tempTitle, //A
        _tempDescription, //B
 
    TextEditingController _textCtrlA = new TextEditingController();
    TextEditingController _textCtrlB = new TextEditingController();
  
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: CustomScrollView(
          slivers: [
            SliverAppBar(
              pinned: true,
              expandedHeight: 250.0,
              actions: [],
              flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                title: Text("Edit space"),
              ),
            ),
            SliverList(
              delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
                [
                  EditTextFieldForm(
                    initialValText: _loadedDeed.title,
                    labelText: "Title",
                    maxLines: 3,
                    textControllerTextForm: _textCtrlA,
                  ),
                  
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class EditTextFieldForm extends StatefulWidget {
  final String labelText;
  final String initialValText;
  final TextEditingController textControllerTextForm;
  final int maxLines;

  EditTextFieldForm({
    @required this.labelText,
    @required this.initialValText,
    @required this.textControllerTextForm,
    @required this.maxLines,
  });

  @override
  _EditTextFieldFormState createState() => _EditTextFieldFormState();
}

class _EditTextFieldFormState extends State<EditTextFieldForm> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
      child: TextFormField(
        controller: widget.textControllerTextForm,
        initialValue: widget.initialValText,
        maxLines: widget.maxLines,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          labelText: widget.labelText,
          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
              Radius.circular(5.0),
            ),
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Please help me..
much appreciate

i suspect the problem could be

1. the modal route passing argument
2. the stateless stateful within page 3 i did something wrong

Edit and Updates:
I try to use future builder but raise another problems and i was struggling to solve

new error [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7xAS.png)

```
      Future<String> _getID() async {
       var _idpass = await ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments as String;
       return _idpass;
     }
   ......
            FutureBuilder(
              future: _getID(),
              builder:
                  (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  return SliverList(
                    delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
                      [
                      
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                } else {
                  Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                }
              },
            )
```

Comment: where you pass data to 3rd page?

Comment: @JohnJoe as u can see from the first image, the most bottom part, theres a  
 Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed(
                      EditDashboardCardDetailsScreen.routeName,
                      arguments: _passData,
                    );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect `findByKey` method haven't returned the object but `_loadedDeed.title` already get called at first place, so it throws the null error. To fix this, I would suggest you to use `FutureBuilder`.

```
FutureBuilder(
        future: Provider.of<DeedsData>(context).findByKey(_deedID),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return EditTextFieldForm(
              initialValText: snapshot.data.title,
              labelText: "Title",
              maxLines: 3,
              textControllerTextForm: _textCtrlA,
            );
          } else {
            return EditTextFieldForm(
              initialValText: "",
              labelText: "Title",
              maxLines: 3,
              textControllerTextForm: _textCtrlA,
            );
          }
        });
```

**Edit**

You can play around with `snapshot.connectionState`.

```
        FutureBuilder(
          future: _getID(),
          builder:(context, snapshot) {
               switch(snapshot.connectionState){
                  case ConnectionState.waiting:
                    return CircularProgressIndicator();
                    break;
                   
                   case ConnectionState.active:
                   // your code;
                  
                   case ConnectionState.done:
                  // your code;
                 
                  default:
                  return Text("Error");
               }
          },
        )
```

Comment: after hours of tries and errors, i realised the problem is really likely like what u mentioned, the _loadedDeed havent really done fetching data, but the textformfield already done running, hence the initialVal is empty,
as such, the future builder i cant really successfully make it, is there any more methods that force things to be fetched before textform been running, otherwise return a circular progress icon?

Comment: yes, you can use `swich-case` to check `snapshot.connectionState`.

Comment: hi senior, can help me check around my edits and updates about future builder? i will be super grateful if we could have a really quick session regarding solve this problems.. tq vmuch in advance.

Comment: thanks so much senior, thought met some probs still, so to be clear, screen init->inter-page data accepted->render widget->substitute value
, correct?